# Case statement with nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a case statement to return true or false if a record is returned in my query.  A lot number is returned it is True and when no lot number returned it is false.  I keep getting just a blank when no record is returned.  The true side works well. I would like it to return false when no record is returned. I am sure it is something simple.  Thanks in advance.

```
declare  @lotnum  nvarchar(100)
set  @lotnum ='3113'


select 
case when LOT_0 = '17-WA411-014' then 'True' else 'False' end 
from  [x3v7].[LIVE].[STOLOT]
where LOT_0 ='17-WA411-014'
group by LOT_0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `where LOT_0 ='17-WA411-014'`

```
select case when LOT_0 = '17-WA411-014' then 'True' else 'False' end 
from  [x3v7].[LIVE].[STOLOT]
group by LOT_0
```

Comment: Yea, that WHERE clause is filtering out results where LOT_0  does not equal '17-WA411-014'  - meaning all the returned rows will be 'True'

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your `where` clause :

So, it would be :

```
select LOT_0, (case when LOT_0 = '17-WA411-014' 
                    then 'True' else 'False' 
               end) 
from  [x3v7].[LIVE].[STOLOT]
group by LOT_0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`IF EXISTS(SELECT 1

                from  [x3v7].[LIVE].[STOLOT]
                where LOT_0 ='17-WA411-014')
    select 
    case when LOT_0 = '17-WA411-014' then 'True' else 'False' end 
    from  [x3v7].[LIVE].[STOLOT]
    where LOT_0 ='17-WA411-014'
    group by LOT_0
ELSE
    SELECT 'False'`

Hope below one helps,